# WinCe cannot connect and consume WCF service

Tags: wcf, compact-framework, windows-ce

I created a test WCFServiceLibrary project leaving the example code created by VS20212, then i created a ConsoleApplication in the same solution and added a web reference to the service.

In my ConsoleApplication i write this:

```
       var ns = new ServiceReference1.Service1();
       Console.WriteLine( ns.GetData( 100 ) );
```

I press F5 and everything seems fine.

**Now i keep my WcfTestClient** (the server hosting my service when launching from visual studio) running and create a new **CompactFramework 2.0 ConsoleApplication project** from VS2008.

**I add a web reference as before**, i compile and distribute my app on my test device I try to execute the same code you see above but i get this error:

"Unable to connect to the remote server" inner exception {"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"}

Dows WcfTestClient have some limitation that do not allow me to connect from outside localhost? How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like you have a connection problem (firewall, wrong IP setup, ...?). You may test your Compact Framework exe on the same computer where you tested with VS2012. The Compact Framework exe files can be run on desktop PC too as long no WinCE only reference is in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change 'localhost' to my actual server ip in my CompactFramework project's app.config since i was remotely debugging an application deployed on a real device :)